# (Sometimes) The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I am using the code below to start threads with a list parameter but sometimes it throws an exception:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

From this line:

```
Thread MoveThread = new Thread(() => MoveTask(ControllerDictionary[i]));
```

How can I fix that error?

Full code:

```
var ControllerDictionary = ConfigFile.ControllerList.Select((c, i) => new { Controller = c, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index % AppSettings.SimultaneousProcessNumber)
    .Select((g, i) => new { GroupIndex = i, Group = g })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.GroupIndex, x => x.Group.Select(xx => xx.Controller).ToList());

for (int i = 0; i < ControllerDictionary.Count; i++)
{
     Thread MoveThread = new Thread(() => MoveTask(ControllerDictionary[i]));
     MoveThread.Start();

     foreach (var Controller in ControllerDictionary[i])
         Logger.Write(string.Format("{0} is in move thread {1}.", Controller.Ip, (i + 1)),EventLogEntryType.Information, AppSettings.LogInfoMessages);
}
```

Comment: What is going on in your MoveTask Method? Is it modifying the ControllerDictionary in anyway?

Comment: No! MoveTask only reads the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're capturing the *variable* `i`, rather than its value. So currently you could have several threads calling `MoveTask` using the same index... and sometimes the value of `i` could be equal to `ControllerDictionary.Count`.

If you take a *copy* of `i` into a variable within the loop, that fixes the problem as you'll get a separate variable on each iteration of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ControllerDictionary.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    Thread MoveThread = new Thread(() => MoveTask(ControllerDictionary[index]));
    ... 
}
```

Or even better, extract the `ControllerDictionary` fetch from the thread entirely:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ControllerDictionary.Count; i++)
{
    var value = ControllerDictionary[i];
    Thread MoveThread = new Thread(() => MoveTask(value));
    ... 
}
```

Additionally, it's not really clear why you're using a dictionary at all. Given that you know the keys will all be in the range `[0, count)` why don't you just use an array? You'd change your query to:

```
var controllerLists = ConfigFile.ControllerList
    .Select((c, i) => new { Controller = c, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index % AppSettings.SimultaneousProcessNumber)
    .Select(g => g.Select(xx => xx.Controller).ToList())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I am using dictionary because i am giving different lists to every task so i collect the lists in a dictionary.

Comment: @petre: That doesn't sound like a reason to me. You could collect the lists in an array instead... that would feel more natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Thread MoveThread = new Thread(() => MoveTask(ControllerDictionary[i]));
```

That anonymous function is going to be executed on a different thread and there is no guarantee that the local variables are going to be valid.